# Create event receiver in sharepoint 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2010, events, sharepoint-2007

which project use to create event receiver for sharepoint 2007 list - sequential workflow or state workflow? i'm using VS 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

Workflows are events which are run via the SharePoint Timer service and can be executed by any server in the farm.

An event receiver is essentially an event handler that will be executed either synchronously or asynchronously (depending on which event you're implementing) on the same server which handled the request that triggered the event receiver.

Visual Studio 2010 does not have much OOTB support for SharePoint 2007. You might consider installing the [WSP Builder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858) extensions (note that the proper download is not the recommended download - you'll need the 2010 BETA 1.4). They give new project types which include event receivers. Note though that there are some quirks with those project types but overall they are very helpful to getting the project set up correctly.

Be sure to read the documentation regarding the folder/file layout of your projects. If done correctly, you can use WSPBuilder to generate your WSPs for you.

A quick search revealed this [blog post](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/WSPBuilder+for+SharePoint+2007+in+Visual+Studio+2010) which might help get you started with regard to project structure. I'm sure there are many, many more references available. Happy coding!

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work or you don't have access or you're not permitted? You don't need WSP Builder but it makes laying out the XML files with your code a lot easier. You can instead search for the proper layouts.